# Getting comments of Facebook social plugin in website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins

I've been trying to take all comments from a forum of a website using the facebook-social-plugin and I don't get the philosophy of how to do it.
Using the Graph API Explorer, I tried:

```
?fields=og_object{comment}&id=https://www.reclamos.cl/reclamo/2015/oct/investing_capital_inversi_n_en_el_mercado_de_divisas
```

but the error is: `"message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (comment) on node type (OpenGraphObject)"`,

then I tried by using:

```
?fields=og_object{comment}&id=220640118006433 (where the 'id' is the plugin id)
```

but the error is:

`"message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (og_object) on node type (Application)",`

I think I'm missing a concept here, all lights to light the road are welcomed!

Comment: It’s `og_object{comments}` (plural), not `og_object{comment}`

Comment: @CBroe thanks! The Code runs, but no results about The comments of The url. Do you know how to fix It?

Comment: You have the comments plugin pointed to `http://www.reclamos.cl/reclamo/2015/oct/investing_capital_inversi_n_en_el_mercado_de_divisas`, but `og:url` is the HTTPS version - those are two different URLs to Facebook. Since you have the comments on the first URL already, you should make og:url the HTTP version too.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on the same problem.
In your case, I looked at the code source html where the Facebook pluging puts the comments and I found the id, if you put this in the api, it works:

`comments/?ids=1065663070140433`

But I have no clue on how to get this id from the original url where the plugin put the comments which I believe you are trying to do.